# Magento 2 Indexer Command Line Mac Parse Error Line 93

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.1.2

Just done a fresh install of Magento 2.1.2 on my Mac running MAMP PHP Version 5.6.10 and MySQL Version 5.6.25. When I attempt to reindex

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

I get the error:

```
Parse error: parse error in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento.dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93
```

Comment: How solved your problem ?